# Go from a list of all directories to a list of all files in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I successfully created a list of all directories and I have a method that makes a list of all files for each directory in the list, but for some reason my method to list all files on the computer throws a null pointer exception. Here's my code:

```
def getFileList(directoryName: String): List[String] = {
    ( new File(directoryName) ).listFiles.filter(_.isFile).map(_.getAbsolutePath).toList
}
def getAllDirs(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val dirList = getDirList( dir )
    @tailrec
    def loop( directories: List[ String ], accList: List[ String ] ): List[ String ] = {
        if ( directories.isEmpty ) accList
        else loop( directories.tail, accList ++: getDirList( directories.head ) )
    }
    loop( dirList, List[ String ]() )
}
def getAllFiles(dir: List[String]): List[String] = dir.flatMap(x => getFileList(x))
```

Here's an alternative method I've tried that failed:

```
def getAllFiles(directories: List[String]): List[String] = {
    def loop(dir: List[String], accList: List[String]): List[String] = {
        if (dir.isEmpty) accList
        else loop(dir.tail, getFileList(dir.head)) ++: accList
    }
    loop( directories, List[String]() )
} // END getFullFileList
```

And here's another

Comment: can you include the stacktrace in the post?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `getDirList()` is called but not defined.

Comment: If a you don't don't have permission to read a directory `.listFiles` will return `null`

Comment: @Dima you should post that comment as an answer..